# assign a USB to KVM virtual machine centos 5.8

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos5, usb

can any one advice how to assign a USB to a guest based on KVM and host is centos 5.8 64-bit ?
when i tried with gui using virt-manager -> add physical device-> usb i got all usb like null 
 despite when i tried lsusb i got the usb detected by host !

Answer (score 0):

Try to us the module kvm and kvm_ and look inside "dmesg|grep -i usb" and via lsusb in the host system if you have all usb ports operational.